# handleSubmit is not working while passing it to child components through react-hook-forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent and child component. In Parent component , submit method are there and the in the child component the Form element is there, Here is the code snipate,

```
function Parent() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
  } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return <Child submit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} register={register}  />
}

function Child({ submit, register }) {
 
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={submit}>
      <input defaultValue="test" {...register("example")} />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Through the above code, if I submit the button then the function is not invoking , no error is showing on the console too.
But If I place the The Form element in the parent component , then it is working perfectly.

But I need to place the Form tag in the Child component. How I fix this issue or is there any other way to do that?

Comment: There is no problem with the above code. Can you replicate this on some online IDE's like https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I just update the latest code snipate , I have placed the Form Element on the child tag and passing the handleSubmit to child compnent.

Answer (score 1):

There is several solutions to this problem.

### Utilize useFormContext

https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useformcontext
Then you are able to pass down the required methods as a context.
Example:

```
import React from "react"
import {
  useForm,
  FormProvider,
  useFormContext
} from "react-hook-form"

export default function App() {
  const methods = useForm()
  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data)

  return ( <
    FormProvider { ...methods
    } >
    // pass all methods into the context
    <
    form onSubmit = {
      methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)
    } >
    <
    NestedInput / >
    <
    input type = "submit" / >
    <
    /form> <
    /FormProvider>
  )
}

function NestedInput() {
  const {
    register
  } = useFormContext() // retrieve all hook methods
  return <input { ...register("test")
  }
  />
}
```

### define the whole form context in the child

You should define the form the same place you define the formContext. But if you want to place a function outside this can be handled as seen here:

```
function Parent() {
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return <Child submit={onSubmit} />
}

function Child({ submit }) {
   const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
  } = useForm();
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>
      <input defaultValue="test" {...register("example")} />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```